# Creating Raster from LAS tiles

Tags: qgis, raster, lidar, las

In ArcGIS, I'd convert LAZ --> LAS... then "Create LAS Dataset" and finally "LAS Dataset to Raster"

Can someone help a brother out and drop the process to get me from point to raster in QGIS?

Comment: You can use Whitebox tools in QGIS for that. Whitebox has an IDW interpolation algorithm you will find useful: https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/available_tools/lidar_tools.html#lidaridwinterpolation

Comment: You want to create a digital surface model / DEM, what is your next step? A hillshade? Tree heights? ...?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are restricted to using QGIS.
In my opinion one of the greatest open-source sorftwares to work with LIDR-Data is [**CloudCompare**](https://cloudcompare.org). It would also spare you the step to first merge your LAZ tiles etc.

There you finde a tool called **Rasterize** which can be used. [See here for the documentation](https://cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/index.php?title=Rasterize) .

You did not specify, what data you want to export as a Raster. CloudCompare allows to export cell statistics from various fields. For example from the Z- Value you can export values such as (among many other options):

- min height
- max height
- height range
- height std. dev.
- average height
- population

You can also export RGB-Values, a Hillshade etc.

The documentation is great and there are also many helpful YouTube-Tutorials, in case you are new to all these data-types and related work-flows.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was just interested in generating a DTM from point cloud so that I can then run hillshade, slope, contour, hydrology and other geopreprocesses against it.

Comment: well, then you should export either the max. height, or the average height (depending on your data) of your Z-value as a raster and you should be good to go. It's quite easy in CloudCompare